# How to refer to currently selected element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a script that would insert `img` element after each link to a certain site with source equal to value of `href` attribute of given link. This is what I came up with:

```
$("a[href*=site.com/img/]").after("<img src="+$(this).attr("href")+">");
```

Problem is, `$(this)` doesn't work (attr() returns `undefined`). Why is it? How to refer to selected link and its argument `href`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Expand it out manually with each(), eg:

```
$("a[href*=site.com/img/]").each (function () {
    $(this).after("<img src="+$(this).attr("href")+">");
});
```

You need to be in the right scope for $(this) to behave as you expect it to, jQuery needs some kind of context to set it.